# Organizing database content with jquery mobile using php

Tags: html

So I have this code :

```
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-widget-content" align="justify">
          <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a" id="clients"><strong>Clients</strong></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" id="freelancers"><strong>Freelancers</strong></div>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

    $query =mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($checkuser > 1) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        extract($row);
            if ($usertype == 'client') {
    echo '<div class="ui-block-a" align="justify"> '.ucfirst($username).'</div>';
           } 
            if ($usertype == 'freelancer') {
    echo '<div class="ui-block-b" align="justify"> '.ucfirst($username).'</div>';
            }       
    }
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
    </strong></div>
```

And it gives out this result : [image: content of the database]

Can someone help me understand why the second column `freelancers` displays the data spaced like that and what I need to change in my code to make it look like the first column, without that vertical spacing ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be thank you for correcting my obscure english...but do you have any suggestions as to how I can go about formatting my columns?

Comment: I'd say : use the correct html element to format them : a table. With div you'd hardly be able to format things in columns and row like you can easily do in a table.

Comment: thanx...but every where I have gone online that has to do with jquery mobile has recommended we not use tables...I thought putting the data in separate blocks would do the trick...maybe I just don't know how to use them properly....smh